# Подключение кастомного TabBarController

Tags: ios, sdk

Добрый день!
В своем проекте я хочу использовать кастомный TabBar, вот ссылка на него:
https://github.com/Yalantis/FoldingTabBar.iOS

Но столкнулся с такой проблемой:

В моем проекте TabBar не является первой страницей, сначала у меня показываются страницы регистрации и входа, затем переход на TabBar, соответственно я не могу подключить кастомный TabBar способом, описанным в мануале:

In AppDelegate method take out an instance of YALFoldingTabBarController from the window.rootViewController and supply it with images for the left and right tabBarItems respectively. Also you can add your own image for the center button of YALFoldingTabBar

```
YALFoldingTabBarController *tabBarController = (YALFoldingTabBarController *) self.window.rootViewController;

//prepare leftBarItems
YALTabBarItem *item1 = [[YALTabBarItem alloc] initWithItemImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nearby_icon"]
                                                  leftItemImage:nil
                                                 rightItemImage:nil];


YALTabBarItem *item2 = [[YALTabBarItem alloc] initWithItemImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"profile_icon"]
                                                  leftItemImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"edit_icon"]
                                                 rightItemImage:nil];

tabBarController.leftBarItems = @[item1, item2];
```

Я попробовал использовать данный код в классе YALFoldingTabBarController, но это ни к чему не привело.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно подключить его?

Сейчас TabBar просто не отображается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я предлагаю вначале убедиться точно, что tabbar не отображается. Надо запустить на симуляторе приложение, перейти на тот  view, где должен быть tabbar.   Нажать на кнопку "Debug view hierarhy". Возможно tabbar просто за пределами видимости.

Comment: По какой-то причине у меня ничего не отображается в Debug view. Может скинуть проект?

Comment: А какой Xcode?  И там, где Project Navigator, должен появиться Debug Navigator (на него еще можно перейти), на этой закладке должно быть дерево View. Там есть UIWindow? И на симуляторе приложение запустилось? Оно должно там работать в это время. В принципе можно скинуть проект мне я попробую посмотреть.

Comment: Я попробовал и на старом и на новом, что-то не то...

Сейчас метод, который создает данный TabBar реализуется в AppDelegate, но этот вариант не подходит, так как первый контроллер у меня не TabBar. Я пытался реализовать его через другие контроллеры, но тогда tabbar не появляется. В общем в проекте все видно будет. Также этот метод я реализовал в классе YALAnimatingTabBarConstants. Он называется setupYALTabBarController
Вот ссылка на проект:
https://yadi.sk/d/dxUMmpBxgTdpB

Comment: Суть в чем. Ты предполагаешь что rootViewController -  это YALFoldingTabBarController.  Но там находится FirstViewController.  Надо вызвать setupYALTabBarController метод когда загружен TabBarController, т.е. значительно позже, не в appDelegat, а в prepareForSegue: например. Когда загружается твой tabBarViewController из сториборда.  Надо почитать по seque.

Comment: У тебя получилось запустить его?)

Comment: я рассказал идею. Решение тут очевидно. Можно попробовать субклассировать YALFoldingTabBarController (заменить в сториборде на этот класс) и вызвать метод в viewDidLoad. У меня нет времени ковыряться.

Comment: Понял, спасибо, сейчас попробую

Comment: кстати, Debug view hierarhy показывает, что tabbarcontroller успешно загружен в твоем проекте после нажатия на кнопку.

Comment: т.е. там осталось только сразу посл загрузки его вызвать этот метод.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. В методе YALFoldingTabBarController.m:

   -(void)setupYALTabBarController

удалить строку

```
YALFoldingTabBarController *tabBarController = (YALFoldingTabBarController *) self.window.rootViewController;
```

далее tabBarController заменить на self.

2. Закомментировать строку (так как тут креш)
   self.selectedIndex = 2;
3. Проверить наличие всех ресурсов (картинок)

Таббар запускается и отображается после 2-го пункта. 
Но лучше запускать этот метод так, как я советовал в комментариях. От сюда его убрать.

Comment: Ураа!!!
Спасибо большое за помощь!!